# Add a header/title to a context menu

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create a style for all context menus in my app. This style will allow me to add a header/title to my context menus. The style I am using right now is as follows

```
<Style x:Uid="someStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_240" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource someBrush}" />
    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_241" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource someBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_242" Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_243" Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Uid="ControlTemplate_30" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Grid x:Uid="Grid_27">
                    <Border x:Uid="Border_25" Margin="1" x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    <StackPanel x:Uid="StackPanel_4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsItemsHost="True" ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger x:Uid="Trigger_76" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter x:Uid="Setter_244" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource someBrush}" TargetName="Border" />
                        <Setter x:Uid="Setter_245" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource someBrush}" TargetName="Border" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This style is working just fine for me but is without the ability to add the header/title. My initial idea was to place a dummy Label here

```
<Grid x:Uid="Grid_27">
                <Border x:Uid="Border_25" Margin="1" x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                <Label Content {bind some way to allow the user to set it}>
                    <Label.Triggers>
                        <some way to hide the header if not set/>
                    <Label.Triggers>
                </Label>
                <StackPanel x:Uid="StackPanel_4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsItemsHost="True" ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </Grid>
```

I was hoping that I could use this label as a bindable header/title for all context menus. The problem I am having is that I do not know how to make this label bindable so that every context menu can have a different header/title. This solution must also be as self contained as possible. I do not want to make everyone who has every used a context menu have to add multiple lines to enable this functionality i.e I want the header to be optional not a requirement on every single menu so it would be great if there was a trigger or something that could hide the header if it was not set

What is the best/cleanest way to achieve this and make it as reusable as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your style just trickle down the binding:

```
<Grid x:Uid="Grid_27" DataContext={Binding}>
            <Border .../>
            <Label Content="{Binding MenuTitle}" 
                   Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
            ...the rest of your style...
        </Grid>
```

in usage, provide data context:

```
<MenuItem DataContext="{Binding SomeViewModel.Menu1}"
         Style={StaticResource yourstyle}>
  ...
```

where Menu1 is property with a type that has "MenuTitle" and "IsVisible" properties

Comment: What would happen if the datacontext was not set? Is there a solution that would not require an IsVisible value? Can a trigger tell if the MenuTitle is null or empty and just not show the header?

Comment: I believe that if your datacontext is not set, you'll get errors/warnings in your output window. If IsVisible is a bool, then you don't have to set it, it's "false" by default. If you don't want to provide binding you could provide defaults through setters in your style, that way the style's properties will change only through triggers. So basiclly, yes, binding isn't required. If you don't provide it, the control just won't display anything (unless defaults are set)

Comment: Hey, I used some of your info along with some other research to come up with a suitable solution. In the end I settled for a second context menu in our style library that they user must specify they want to use through `Style={StaticResource yourstyle}`. Changing the existing context style was causing issues with existing context menus in other places. Thanks